# skill-sample-nodejs-highlowgame - how to use the skill with german?

Tags: alexa-skills-kit

I changed the language into german, adjusted the languageStrings.js. While testing it says, that there is a problem with the skill. Any clue?

link: https://github.com/alexa-samples/skill-sample-nodejs-highlowgame/blob/master/instructions/test-using-simulator.md

greetings karsten

I changed the language into german, adjusted the languageStrings.js. While testing it says, that there is a problem with the skill.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to create all the intents and slot types in German and then train your model! If not the skill will not work in German!

Comment: Thanx Xavier, after reviewing I detected the fault you mentioned..